# Clothes wont attach correctly to model

Tags: rigging

I connected the clothes to the model using the data transfer modifier but every time I do it attaches but some parts of the clothing are off.

[image]

https://workupload.com/file/suXApfjqtxN

Comment: Hello maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots do you have a discord or something? it says my file is to big

Comment: or use another platform like workupload?

Comment: @moonboots here you go https://workupload.com/file/suXApfjqtxN

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Answer (score 0):

The default coat shape is already bad as it doesn't follow the shape of the armature or body:

[image]

What you can do is keep the coat selected, swtich to *Sculpt* mode, select the *Pose* brush:

[image]

Then change the coat shape so that it matches the body and armature:

[image]

That said, the coat topology is pretty bad, and the weight is not very good, you'll need to rework that. For example you should smooth the weight: Select the armature, shift select the coat, switch to *Weight Paint* mode, select all the bones with <kbd>A</kbd> and *Weights > Smooth*, and increase the *Iterations* value in the *Operator Box* to make the smooth more gradual:

[image]